# Why do properties like NSString work without memory allocation whereas a property of UITextField doesNot work unless I alloc Space to it...?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, properties

If I create a property of type NSString without allocating space to it and assign some value to it , it works. Where as I do the same thing for a UITextField it doesn't..? I am creating a textfield programmatically.... any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I have created two properties in .h of SecondViewController...

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *text;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textField;
```

Now if I create a new object secondViewController and say do this...

```
   secondViewController.text=@"Second View Controller";
```

this value is retained even though I did not alloc Memory to it...

and if i try to do the same thing for a textfield object this does not happen unless I allocate memory to it..

here is my SecondViewController...

```
//
//  SecondViewController.m
//  Tester
//
//  Created by Ankit on 4/16/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize  text,textField;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"The text is %@",text);

//   textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40)]; (if I `uncomment this than only this textField is visible)`
    textField.frame=CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40);
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    textField.placeholder = @"enter text";
    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;    
    [self.view addSubview:textField];

//    textfield=[[UITextField alloc] init];
//    textfield.frame=CGRectMake(10,10,60, 30);
//    [self.view addSubview:textfield];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.text=nil;
    self.textField=nil;
    NSLog(@"viewDidUnLoad");
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
-(void)dealloc{
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
    [text release];
    [textField release];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Comment: May be show some code? It is hard to figure out what you're asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A property is just a reference to an object and the 'space' has to come from somewhere else.  The only real difference with NSString is that the space is often in the form of a literal so you don't see the allocation directly.  @"Hello" is a real object that you can reference but in other cases you use [[NSString alloc] init...] constructions that are the same as [[UITextField alloc] init...] constructions.

Comment: where was the memory allocated to "text"..?

Comment: In code, it was allocated at the point where you typed @"<string literal>".

Comment: ok very well explained. I have one more doubt though.. then why does textfields added via XIB's don't need to be allocated...?

Comment: Because the objects that those references point to are built in memory as part of XIB loading.  (People sometimes talk about XIBs as a collection of "freeze-dried" objects that get reconstituted when the program runs.)

Comment: one last doubt... I still need to release this object returned by  @"<string literal>"...? or is it autoreleased..?

Comment: You can think of it as autoreleased and safely treat it that way.  In truth, the word 'returned' is a bit misleading because the compiler puts them in a special section of your binary where they won't **really** be deallocated.  I don't know the details of how and where it does that and have never needed to.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

`NSString` is a special object. Unlike `UITextField` which is built upon many other things, the `@` character you saw is a special hint to the compiler that this is an `NSString`. In other words, the compiler is doing the alloc and init for you. What it does is pretty much `[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:"your string"]`. The code is more of a short-hand equivalent to save you time.

`String` is actually not a primitive data type like `int`. Compiler treat it the same as an array, or memory buffer. But people tend to have the habit of using it as a primitive data type. Thus similar special treatment is happening in lots of programming languages.

`UITextField` is nothing similar to a data type. It's an object, and it's heavyweight. The compiler didn't know much about its nature except for it's an object. And it doesn't make that much sense (I mean they could) to optimize the syntax this way. So it ended up with the behavior you saw.

Comment: ok very well explained. I have one more doubt though.. then why does textfields added via XIB's don't need to be allocated...?

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava Hmm.. ``UITextField`` in XIB does have to allocated. You see, again, XIB is a special treatment. It's an XML file used by the Cocoa Framework. It evaluates its content, and run lots of ``UITextField`` alloc and init on your behalf. In the end it's still a time saving feature. But I should mention that objective-c and cocoa aren't the same thing. ``UITextField`` alloc automation is in higher level (run-time) than ``NSString``, which is a compile-time feature.

Answer (score 0):

NSString has a convenience macro built in to do `NSString *bob = @"bob";`

Currently, no other classes have this exact notation (Array Dictionary and Set re getting it very soon)

To use a UITextField you have to properly do

```
UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc]init]
```

and then call `tf.text = @"";`

EDIT: the `=@""` is just a wrapper around creating a new string with alloc and init. it just hides it :)